# Start intent inside a broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have used the following code to start a broadcastreceiver which calls a new intent after its designted time, but the problem is the intent is not being called.
The alarm is called by a button on screen, when the button is clicked after designated time the new intent is expected to start.

```
private void alarm(){
            br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Rise and Shine!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };
    Log.v("ranjith","Inside setup");
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.example.ads.test"));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(),test.class),0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not calling `set()`, `setRepeating()`, or `setInexactRepeating()` on the `AlarmManager`, to schedule an event to occur that will send your broadcast.

Second, your `PendingIntent` is incorrect. Use the following to line up with your `IntentFilter`:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.example.ads.test"), 0);
```

Third, using a dynamically-registered receiver with `AlarmManager` is rather unusual, as it means that your alarm will only be valid while your application is running.